# nested placeholders in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am trying to pass a function into a filter which itself is nested in deeper functions

Conceptually, something like this (broken) example:

```
const testData = [
  {foo: "foo", bar: ""}
];

const myFilter = a => !R.isEmpty(a);

const clean = R.when(
    R.either(R.is(Array), R.is(Object)),
    R.pipe(
        R.map(a => clean(R.__)(a)),
        R.filter(R.__)
    )
)

const cleanEmpties = clean(myFilter);

cleanEmpties(testData); //fail: should not include `bar`, but it does
```

What's the right way to do this?

Just to illustrate the point, this hardcoded alternative does work as intended:

```
const cleanEmpties = R.when(
    R.either(R.is(Array), R.is(Object)),
    R.pipe(
        R.map(a => cleanEmpties(a)),
        R.filter(myFilter)
    )
)

cleanEmpties(testData); //working, does not include `bar`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of how `R.__` is interpreted when referenced multiple times in the same function.  If you haven't passed in enough arguments, a curried function will return that expects more arguments to fill up the gaps.

```
R.gt(4,3) // true
R.gt(R.__, R.__)(4, 3) //true
R.gt(R.__, R.__)(4)(3) //true
R.gt(R.__, R.__)(4) // function n(r){return 0===arguments.length||b(r)?n:t.apply(this,arguments)}
```

If you change your function syntax to accept an explicit arg, the code works as expected:

```
const clean = f => R.when(
  R.either(R.is(Array), R.is(Object)),
  R.pipe(
    R.map(a => clean(f)(a)),
    R.filter(f)
  )
);
```